# function in $ C^1$ has same sign in two adjacent intervals then $x_0$ must be at least a double zero

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, roots

I find the following claim in a book: Suppose $f\in C^1[a,b]$ and $x_0\in (a,b)$ is a zero of $f$, i.e., $f(x_0)=0$. Assume that $f(x)>0$ for all $x\in[a,b]\setminus \{x_0\}$. Then $x_0$ must be at least a double zero of $f$.

My try: If $x_0$ is a single zero, then $f(x)=(x-x_0)g(x)$ with $g(x_0)\neq 0$. Since $g$ is also continuous then either $g(x)>0$ or $g(x)<0$ in a small neighbor of $x_0$.  If $g(x)>0$ in a neighbor of $x_0$. Then $f(x)=(x-x_0)g(x)<0$ when $x<x_0$ which is a contradiction.

My question is why do we need the assumption $f\in C^1[a,b]$ ? It seems that $f\in C[a,b]$ is enough to let the claim be true.

Comment: What about $f(x) = \lvert x-x_0\right$? It satisfies the “same sign” condition but doesn’t have a double zero at $x_0$.

Comment: @User8128 Oh yeah. That's a nice counterexample. But where did I make a mistake in my proof. Or how to use the condition $C^1$?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about the context, but what is exactly meant here by double zero? The function

$$f(x) = \begin{cases}e^{-\frac{1}{x^2}} & x \neq 0 \\ 0 & x = 0 \end{cases}, x \in [-1, 1]$$

has only $1$ zero at the origin and is positive everywhere else. What is meant here exactly by the order of the $0$ at the origin here? The first non-zero derivative at $x_0$?

The reason we're dealing with $C^{1}$ is to make sure that the notion derivative is even defined for the function. Otherwise, the function $g(x)=|x|, x \in [-1, 1]$ would also only have one zero at $x=0$ but it is not even differentiable at that point.

The way I would prove this question is to assume the opposite(as you did) and conclude that $\exists \epsilon > 0$ where $f(x_0 - \epsilon) < 0$ if the first derivative were non-zero, which would contradict the initial assumption that the function is always non-negative.

edit: By the opposite I mean "suppose the function has a non-zero derivative at $x_0$".

Comment: Double zero means the zero has the multiplicity 2.

Comment: But is the function necessarily analytic? or a polynomial? All we know is that it's in $C^{1}$ and it could be non-analytic.

Comment: Yes, we only know that the function is in $C^1$.

Comment: If the function is not differentiable at $x_0$, then how is multiplicity of the root even defined? What is the multiplicity of the root of $|x|$ at $x_0=0$?

Comment: I made an edit to my post, I misunderstood part of the question. My apologies.